# Obtaining pathname of current route in React Router w/browserHistory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history

there seems to be some disagreement between various sources on what the most efficient way of obtaining the pathname of the current url using React Router is (using `browserHistory`). Below is a snippet of my Provider and routes:

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={Store}>
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path="/tools/customer-lookup" component={CustomerLookupApp} />
                <Route path="/tools/customer-lookup/profile/:id" component={CustomerLookupProfileWrapper} />
                <Route path="/tools/customer-lookup/profile/:id/store/:storeid" component={CustomerLookupStoreProfileWrapper} />
                <Route path="/tools/customer-lookup/profile/:id/store/:storeid/transaction/:transid" component={CustomerLookupStoreItemsWrapper} />
            </Router>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('customer-lookup-main'));
});
```

Tried logging `this.props.location.pathname` in various components but always comes up undefined. Same thing with `this.context`.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your codes seem correct, except your paths of routes are a little redundant. You could use child routes to decrease the length of `path`. You may post the complete codes for debugging.red

Comment: @JasonXu except that I'm trying to **avoid** nesting one component within another when traveling to a child route. Rather, the routes (while I agree they look terribly redundant) are linking to a completely different view of the single page app and not necessarily reusing any of the parent components. If there's a better way to accomplish **that** and still nest routes, I'm interested in hearing about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `this.props.location.pathname` will not be available in "various" components, it will only be available in your route handing components. i.e. `CustomerLookupApp`, `CustomerLookupProfileWrapper`, `CustomerLookupStoreProfileWrapper`, `CustomerLookupStoreItemsWrapper`.

If you need the pathname further down the tree then you can pass it down as props.

Comment: Can I still pass it like so? `<CustomerProfile location={this.props.location} />` I'm getting an `undefined` on `this`.